# How to stop JQM from styling a page?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a JQM app with one specific page that I do not want styled.

All I have found so far is `data-role='none'` - but I don't want to have to apply that to every element on the page... Is there a way to turn if off just for this one page?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `data-enhance="false"` in conjunction with `$.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled=true` to stop the auto-enhancement that jQuery Mobile does to a pseudo-page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).on('mobileinit', function () {
    $.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled = true;
});
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.js"></script>

<div data-enhance="false" data-role="page">
    ...
</div>​
```

The reason you have to change the `ignoreContentEnabled` flag is because it's CPU intensive to search parent elements for the `data-attribute`, so this is turned-off by default.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ZtJyL/1/

Answer (score 4):

As I already pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15987014/how-to-remove-jquery-mobile-styling), you can also use the official, [theme-less version of the CSS](http://jquerymobile.com/download/) built specifically to allow the design of a custom theme.

In my experience, using hacks like `data-enhance="false"` and `data-role="none"` often breaks things with structural, non-thematic CSS as well.

With this method you are able to keep all jQuery Mobile basic functionality, you don't have to fight with hacks and overrides all the time, and you get a lighter CSS as a bonus.