# jquery mobile escape part of a page <div> (dynamically created)

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, jquery, markup

Been trying to escape part of a page from jquery mobile since I already have a different plugin processing that part of the page turn.js but I can't seem to escape it... this is on a dynamic div that is processed by another jquery plugin. here is a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/adamsurfari/DpQQV/ this is how the flipbook is supposed to work http://jsfiddle.net/blasten/A9a7E/

I am already using

```
<div data-enhance="false" data-role="none" id="flipbook">
</div>
```

but the images still does not appear. Is there a different way to escape divs and what is inside them from jquery mobile?

Configuration of the page:

```
<title></title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="zip/zip.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="zip/deflate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="zip/zip-ext.js"></script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).on('mobileinit', function () {
            $.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled = true;
        });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="turn.js"></script>
```

This is the normal output from turn.js:

```
<div data-enhance="false" id="flipbook"
     style="position: relative; width: 1024px; height: 360px; -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
    <div class="turn-page-wrapper" page="1"
         style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; width: 512px; height: 360px; top: 0px; right: 0px; left: auto; bottom: auto; z-index: 56;">
        <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; overflow: hidden; z-index: auto; width: 626px; height: 626px; -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 100%;">
            <div data-enhance="false" class="turn-page p1"
                 style="width: 512px; height: 360px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; bottom: auto; right: auto; -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 100%;">
                <img width="512px" src="filesystem:http://localhost:8080/persistent/LEGO/CATALOGO%202013_001.jpg"></div>
        </div>
        <div style="top: 0px; left: 0px; overflow: hidden; z-index: 1; width: 512px; height: 360px; background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 100% 100%, 100% 100%, color-stop(0.8, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.298039)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0))); display: none;"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="pointer-events: none; position: absolute; top: -50px; left: -8px; overflow: visible; z-index: auto; display: none;">
        <div style="position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 520px; overflow: hidden; z-index: 56; width: 626px; height: 626px; -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 100%; -webkit-transform: translate3d(512px, -266px, 0px) rotate(-90deg); display: none;">
            <div style="position: absolute; top: auto; left: 0px; overflow: visible; z-index: auto; width: 512px; height: 360px; right: auto; bottom: 0px; -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 100%; -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) translate3d(0px, 360px, 0px);">
                <div style="cursor: default; width: 360px; height: 512px; -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%; -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);">
                    <div data-enhance="false" class="turn-page p2"
                         style="width: 512px; height: 360px; -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;">
                        <div class="turn-page p4" style="width: 200px; height: 300px;"> Page 2</div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; overflow: hidden; z-index: 1; width: 360px; height: 512px; background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 0%, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(0.8, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)), to(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)));"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="turn-page-wrapper" page="2"
         style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; width: 512px; height: 360px; top: 0px; left: 0px; right: auto; bottom: auto; z-index: 0; display: none;"></div>
    <div class="turn-page-wrapper" page="3"
         style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; width: 512px; height: 360px; top: 0px; right: 0px; left: auto; bottom: auto; z-index: 55;">
        <div data-enhance="false" class="turn-page p3" style="width: 512px; height: 360px;">
            <div class="turn-page p4" style="width: 200px; height: 300px;"> Page 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is the output with jquerymobile with data-enhanced="false", jquerymobile still messes around with the code that is inside the data-enhanced="false" DIV:

```
<div data-enhance="false" id="flipbook"
     style="position: relative; width: 400px; height: 300px; -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
    <div class="turn-page-wrapper ui-page ui-body-c" tabindex="0"
         style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; width: 200px; height: 300px; top: 0px; right: 0px; left: auto; bottom: auto; z-index: 8;">
        <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; overflow: hidden; z-index: auto; width: 361px; height: 361px; -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 100%;">
            <div class="hard turn-page p1"
                 style="width: 200px; height: 300px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; bottom: auto; right: auto; -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 100%;">
                Turn.js
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="top: 0px; left: 0px; overflow: hidden; z-index: 1; width: 200px; height: 300px; background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 100% 100%, 100% 100%, color-stop(0.8, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.298039)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0))); display: none;"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="pointer-events: none; display: none; position: absolute; top: -193.1875px; left: -15px; overflow: visible; z-index: auto;">
        <div style="position: absolute; top: 193.1875px; left: 215px; overflow: hidden; z-index: 8; display: none; width: 361px; height: 361px; -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 100%; -webkit-transform: translate3d(200px, -61px, 0px) rotate(-90deg);">
            <div style="position: absolute; top: auto; left: 0px; overflow: visible; z-index: auto; width: 200px; height: 300px; right: auto; bottom: 0px; -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 100%; -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) translate3d(0px, 300px, 0px);">
                <div style="cursor: default; width: 300px; height: 200px; -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%; -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);">
                    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; overflow: hidden; z-index: 1; width: 300px; height: 200px; background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 0%, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(0.8, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)), to(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)));"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="turn-page-wrapper ui-page ui-body-c" tabindex="0"
         style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; width: 200px; height: 300px; top: 0px; left: 0px; right: auto; bottom: auto; z-index: 0; display: none;">
        <div class="hard turn-page p2" style="width: 200px; height: 300px; -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="turn-page-wrapper ui-page ui-body-c" tabindex="0"
         style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; width: 200px; height: 300px; top: 0px; right: 0px; left: auto; bottom: auto; z-index: 7;">
        <div id="page1-test" class="turn-page p3" style="width: 200px; height: 300px;"> Page 1 <a href="#"
                                                                                                  data-role="button"
                                                                                                  id="test-button">Dynamic
            Button</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="turn-page-wrapper ui-page ui-body-c" tabindex="0"
         style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; width: 200px; height: 300px; top: 0px; left: 0px; right: auto; bottom: auto; z-index: 0; display: none;">
        <div class="turn-page p4" style="width: 200px; height: 300px;"> Page 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="turn-page-wrapper ui-page ui-body-c" tabindex="0"
         style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; width: 200px; height: 300px; top: 0px; right: 0px; left: auto; bottom: auto; z-index: 0; display: none;">
        <div class="turn-page p5" style="width: 200px; height: 300px;"> Page 3</div>
    </div>
```

As is possible to see jqueryMobile still messes around with the code that is inside the div:

For instance:

```
<div class="turn-page-wrapper" page="1"
```

is transformed into:

```
<div class="turn-page-wrapper ui-page ui-body-c" tabindex="0"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop JQM from styling a page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014609/how-to-stop-jqm-from-styling-a-page) Short answer: `data-role="none"` does not work when set on a container, and `data-enhance="false"` only works if `$.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled` is set to `true` in a `mobileinit` handler.

Comment: I have $.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled = true; it still won't work properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Fix:

Change this:

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).on('mobileinit', function () {
            $.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled = true;
        });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="turn.js"></script>
```

to this:

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).on('mobileinit', function () {
            $.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled = true;
        });
    </script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="turn.js"></script>
```

**[mobileinit](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/docs/api/globalconfig.html)** must be initialized before a jquery Mobile is initialized.

## Example:

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/UZwpj/

#### HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://www.dragan-gaic.info/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>           
        <script>
            $(document).on('mobileinit', function () {
            $.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled = true;
            });
        </script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="index">
            <div data-theme="a" data-role="header" data-enhance="false">
                <h3>
                    First Page
                </h3>
                <a href="#second" class="ui-btn-right">Next</a>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">
                <a href="#" data-role="button" id="test-button">Test button</a>
                <!-- Every content inside this div will not be enhanced -->
                <div data-enhance="false">
                    <a href="#" data-role="button" id="test-button">Test button</a>                
                    <div>
                        <a href="#" data-role="button" id="test-button">Test button</a>                
                    </div>                
                </div>
                <a href="#" data-role="button" id="test-button">Test button</a>
            </div>

            <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-enhance="false">
                <h3>
                    Footer
                </h3>
            </div>
        </div>   
    </body>
</html>
```

## Edit:

Only possible solution for dynamically added content is data-role="none" attribute because data-enhance="false"only works on a content loaded from the file.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/eUH56/

Comment: Still does not work for some reason... I have added the output and the expected output.

Comment: It must work, I made you a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/UZwpj/ take a look and ask if you have more questions.

Comment: It works on static pages, but on divs created on a button press event it appears not to work.

Comment: I hope you understand this functionality was never intended to work with dynamically added content. If you want to prevent dynamically added content markup enhancement use data-role="none" because nothing else will work. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/eUH56/

Comment: So there isn't a way to control everything that happens inside a DIV in jQueryMobile? What I want to do is, <!-- This DIV is outside of jQueryMobile --> <div id="dynamicdiv"></div> inside that div I have another plugin creating other divs, in this case turn.js image gallery. Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: If you want to do this, your <div id="dynamicdiv"></div> must exist from the beginning with an attribute data-enhance="false", like this <div id="dynamicdiv" data-enhance="false"></div>. Only then your dynamically added content is not going to be enhanced. But it want work if your container <div id="dynamicdiv"></div> is created dynamically like rest of your content. I have created you new example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/tE2hr/. If you take a look, container <div data-enhance="false" id="test-container"> is preventing enhancement....

Comment: ...even if you add new dynamic content into it and trigger pagecreate to restyle everything, new content will stay without jQuery Mobile styling. I hope you understood me.

Comment: Let me try to add turn.js to that example and see if it works. Thanks again

Comment: Ok, mail me if you still cant make it work and I will find a solution for you.

Comment: I have added the library that I am using to the fiddle...http://jsfiddle.net/pgFe9/4/ it's not working with the turn.js library, it still styles inside the div.

Comment: Still cant find a problem in your example. I have added a jQM button inside a flipbook container and it is not styled: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/pgFe9/5/

Comment: The problem is that on my code the flipbook is not working, I have to look at what is different on my fiddle to see what changed. But thanks I can see that it is working on your fiddle, on mine it is not.

Comment: This is a fix: #flipbook div {display: block !important;} Is this all or do you also want something else?

Comment: That was it, that CSS the issue. Thank you. Actually it still gets styled, even though now it works <div class="turn-page-wrapper ui-page ui-body-c" should be just turn-page-wrapper

Comment: Crap there is still something wrong... I have updated the question with the information. I still get <div class="turn-page-wrapper" page="1" processed into <div class="turn-page-wrapper ui-page ui-body-c" tabindex="0" so the output even though it works, it does not work as it should. This is very frsutrating.

Comment: So basically your problem is that you have unwanted classes added to your page elements. Do they cause you any problems?

Comment: unfortunately they do, turn.js works but not as expected, it flips pages in weird angles, and does not respect page order (div page attribute gets eliminated), at first it looked like that CSS fixed worked, but then I flipped the pages and they are out of order, and present strange effects, using images. Still trying to figure out why this is happening.

Comment: Why dont you load it inside a iframe? That is a only way you can prevent jQuery mobile from changing your content.

Comment: I think I need to change libraries to something that is compatible with jquery mobile. or modify the library - that i am trying to do right now. iframe would be last resourte, I need to change what is inside many times, for some reason the turn.js library is reading stuff in the DOM that was modified by jQM - probably parent stuff and adding it to the wrapper divs, WHY I HAVE NO IDEA?

Comment: Turn.JS is not usable with jquery mobile. So I dropped it and picked a different solution. Thanks Gajotres for all your help.

Comment: @DanMendes which solution did you use?

Comment: I gave up on turn.js did not find a proper way to do it inside of jQueryMobile so I simply point to a regular page instead, that way jQuery Mobile does not get in the way