# Exclude div from JQuery mobile?

Tags: jquery

I have a form that works fine without JQuery.
The form has 2 text inputs and a "file upload". The "file upload" is a DIV with a few inner SPAN elements. 
If I change the form to JQuery mobile, the "file upload" doesn't render the right way anymore. Is there a way to show this "file upload" the same way as without JQuery mobile, while the rest elements are shown with JQuery?

Thanks,
-ioan

Edit: Here is the template I'm using with JQuery:

```
<div data-role="page" id="reportselect">

<div data-role="header">
    <a href="" id="BTNCLOSE" data-theme="b">Close</a>
    <h1>Web to Fax</h1>
</div><!-- /header -->
<div data-role="content">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="ETONAME">To (Name)</label>
        {%eToName%}
    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="ESUBJECT">Subject</label>
        {%eSubject%}
    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="MTOFAXNUMBER">Fax number(s)</label>
        <textarea name="MTOFAXNUMBER" id="MTOFAXNUMBER"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="MMESSAGE">Message</label>
        <textarea name="MMESSAGE" id="MMESSAGE"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div id="UPLOADER_DIV" class="UPLOADERCSS" name="UPLOADER" tabindex="5"></div>
    <a href="" id="BTNSENDFAX" data-role="button" data-theme="b">Send fax now!</a>
</div><!-- /content -->
<div data-role="footer">
    <h4>Web to Fax</h4>
</div><!-- /footer -->
```

The element with the problem is:

```
<div id="UPLOADER_DIV" class="UPLOADERCSS" name="UPLOADER" tabindex="5"></div>
```

Here is how the pages without and with JQuery looks after a **SUCCESSFUL** upload: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0ppA.jpg

The "Upload failed" should be actually hidden.

**Edit3:** Here are the two pages, with and without JQuery Mobile: https://secure.ipfax.net/withJQuery.htm and
https://secure.ipfax.net/withoutJQuery.htm

Comment: A person with 7 badges should know not to ask such a question without providing code.

Comment: Sorry. I added the code.

Comment: "doesn't show the right way anymore" Can you describe what you expect versus what you are getting?

Comment: @Sharlike Here is how the pages without and with JQuery look: http://imgur.com/a/GkqkL

Comment: I know someone asked you to add code but as a suggestion, something a little more succinct would make it easier - eg the elements in question, the CSS styling them and the JS (if any) which modifies their appearance. That said, I'm a little unclear. What do you mean, exactly, by `If I change the form to JQuery mobile`? Do you simply mean loading jQuery on the page or when you assign a role?

Comment: This is the element: <div id="UPLOADER_DIV" class="UPLOADERCSS" name="UPLOADER" tabindex="5"></div> and I have it identical in both, with JQuery mobile and without. The problem is that JQuery changes the look of this control and that what I'm trying to accomplish. To make this control unaffected by jquery (looks and functionality)

Comment: Reformulated my prev. comment so it's more clear: This is the element: <div id="UPLOADER_DIV" class="UPLOADERCSS" name="UPLOADER" tabindex="5"></div> and I have it identical in both, with JQuery mobile and without. The problem is that JQuery changes the look of this control and what I'm trying to accomplish is to make this control unaffected by jquery (looks and functionality)

Comment: Where is your jquery code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two suggestions on this questions first is the data-enhancement that is for the jquery mobile

> data-enhance="false"

Add this to your div

> The "Upload failed" should be actually hidden.

Another one is that when your file upload failed you want to hide div is

```
.uploader-upload-fail
{
display:none;
}
```

Add this css to your class file and your i hope this will help you in your solutions regards....:) ask me if you have confusion

Comment: This helped me find the solution. I changed the style for all the div elements in the upload control and now the control is rendered the right way. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div id="UPLOADER_DIV" class="UPLOADERCSS" name="UPLOADER" tabindex="5" data-enhance="false"></div>
```

Note the `data-enhance="false"` attribute added to the div. This should prevent jquery mobile from enhancing the content of the div (changing the styling and functionality).

Comment: Still doesn't work. After researching your answer, I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014609/how-to-stop-jqm-from-styling-a-page but even with the ignoreContentEnabled = true, still doesn't work. The <div id="UPLOADER_DIV"... still gets messed up.

Comment: Here are the two pages, with and without JQuery Mobile: https://secure.ipfax.net/withJQuery.htm and
https://secure.ipfax.net/withoutJQuery.htm

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Mobile doesn't do anything to disable file uploads.  It just doesn't style them due to browser security restrictions and you can't upload files with the AJAX navigation system.

If you want to use file uploads with jQuery Mobile you have to do two things:
1)  Turn off Ajax navigation using data-ajax="false" on your form definition because you can't upload files using Ajax.
2)  Specify the appropriate encoding type of enctype="multipart/form-data" on your form.

Comment: The upload works fine with and without JQuery. The problem I have is that the Upload element doesn't render correctly under JQuery. Here is how the with and without JQuery the page looks after an upload. Both uploads were successful:  imgur.com/a/GkqkL

Comment: This doesn't answer my question in any way or form. I need to show the "upload file" control the same way in both, with and without JQuery. The upload already works fine in both situations, just the rendering of the control (how it looks) it's broken in JQuery.

Comment: thats why i asked to verify that this was not the problem..all too often its the little things like this that are overlooked.